# Who are these fabric superheroes?

Tags: marvel, dc, character-identification

I’ve acquired some some superhero fabric but have trouble identifying some of them.

[image: various superheroes]

Batman and Hulk seem obvious, but who are the rest of them?

Comment: The problem here is the fabric manufacturer is making clearly unlicensed fabric. So while Batman is kinda like Batman, and Hulk is kinda like Hulk, a lot of them are meant to be so generic as to avoid DC/Marvel loosing their lawyers on them. I mean, is the blue-suit meant to be Superman or Captain America? Contrast this with [officially licensed fabric](https://www.fabric.com/buy/0540039/marvel-kawaii-character-tiles-multi?CAWELAID=172000510001406785)

Comment: Points for using the original mustard-yellow Daredevil, though...

Comment: @Machavity I'd put money on *Captain America*

Comment: A lot of the "identify these..." questions we've had in the past have been for things that were technically fan-art and not necessarily license-accurate. No difference here.

Comment: Then there's Flash and Green Lantern very clearly for me. I think they were really designed to be recognisable, if highly stylized. Come on, we can do this.

Comment: it's all opinion based unless the original manufacturer / designer weighs in. By definition, being ambiguous enough to avoid copyright infringement lends itself to interpretation (ie - opinion)

Comment: Where did you get this from? Is there a makers tags on it?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. Captain America
2. Ms. Marvel
3. Batman
4. The Flash
5. Greatest American Hero
6. The Incredible Hulk
7. Green Lantern (possibly Alan Scott with cape) (or [Ecological Girl](https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/ecological-superhero-woman-in-green-costume-and-cape-eco-concept-vector-id823315022))
8. Spider-Man
9. Daredevil sans horns?
10. Wolverine (brown and yellow costume)
11. Daredevil (mustard costume)
12. Spiderwoman? Dark-haired Supergirl? Dark-haired Captain Marvel?

Comment: I'd say 7 = Green Lantern, 8 = Deadpool. Thoughts ?

Comment: 12 Supergirl but with dark hair to avoid licensing issues?

Comment: @Kalissar or 7'coukd be The Green Arrow with a mask on.

Comment: This looks like a kids pillow, Deadpool would be unlikely.

Comment: Number 8 is clearly meant to be Spider Man - but again, it's very subjective

Comment: I've downvoted in line with [the comment above](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/62709/machavity). Although it's relatively easy to guess who some of these are but in the absence of a quote from the makers (about which characters they ripped off), this is pure guesswork.

Comment: @Valorum That's how almost all of our "identify the characters on this X" work. Even the recent one that was _posted by the maker_ including guesswork by the answerers, and no input from the OP (AKA creator). That's never seemed to have been a reason to DV people trying to answer about unlicensed artwork before, not sure why you're starting now.

Comment: @WebHead - what "recent" one? A link would be helpful for context. Also - there's a difference between unlicensed artwork of copyrighted characters, vs knockoffs meant to be ambiguous enough to skirt copyright/trademark. (which is what this is)

Comment: @NKCampbell https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/195553/can-we-identify-all-the-characters-in-this-ultimate-space-battle-poster

Comment: You should note that some of the creatures/elements in that poster are amalgamations of multiple works, requiring us to completely guess what the composite properties are.

Comment: But you're not guessing who they are, you're guessing *who they look a bit like*. The designer might have entirely different names for them