# Can we identify all the characters in this "Ultimate Space Battle" poster?

Tags: character-identification, object-identification

*Disclosure: I am the creator of this poster.*

[image: an image of a spacebattle, featuring hundreds of participants from different franchises]

[image: an image of a spacebattle, featuring hundreds of participants from different franchises]
*<sub>Click for higher resolution image</sub>*

Can we identify which properties they come from and who they are?

Comment: Not without a much higher resolution image. :)

Comment: Maybe this one will be better https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Whgvq7rQivEjP1p48IL8qdSG5Ta0SFDF

Comment: Given that [OP is evidently the creator of this (commercially available) image](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46930983#46930983) and has failed to disclose their affiliation on the original question, I've flagged this as spam; https://www.artstation.com/chekavo

Comment: @EgorKlyuchnyk I've added a note to your post that you are the creator of the image since you claimed as such in chat. I understand that you might not want to disclose the fact that you created it (since you wouldn't need to ask about the characters you drew). However, [you *must* disclose the fact that you created the work](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/promotion); failure to do so is considered [spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/299342).

Comment: Hello @Null . Sorry about that, I'm new on this site so I could missed some rules. Thank you for edition post. I just did not want to appear here like "Hey, check out my art". I thought that ask a question will be more interesting.

Comment: I downvoted the question because I don't like how you posted the question about a poster you created. I'd have downvoted even if you had disclosed your affiliation from the start, because even then it seems like an advertising post.  At least most of the other similar poster images in character-id questions don't have distracting watermarks.  @Valorum: makes sense, but since Null decided that the post can stay  (unless OP deletes it) after I flagged for moderator attention (which you may not have known), it probably won't matter.

Comment: @Egor The policy to disclose your affiliation, which Null (a moderator) pointed to, is mandatory. See also https://stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy under “Spam”. Don't try to claim ignorance next time. Note also SE's policy https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing (also mentioned in the text at the footer of every page) that if you embed your poster image into the question, you are giving a copyright license to everyone to distribute the image under the terms of the Creative Commons BY-SA 3.0 license.

Comment: I knew I've seen this drawing style before! See our largest multi-identification question https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/171218/4918 "Universe: 113 Character Poster" for another poster drawn by the same hand.

Comment: @onewho - I think we should post the higher quality link without the watermarking; https://i.imgur.com/l5HpXqh.jpg

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because they are asking about their own poster and it's a useless question that they know the answer to.

Comment: We have character identification posts before. Askers can also answer their own posts so OP creating the image is irrelevant in my opinion. If this question closes because of this, I will reupload the images and ask the same question myself and since I am not the creator, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: From [the help files](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) on what not to ask: **"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."**  This violates that principle; if the poster is the creator, he knows the answer and there is no real question -- he's just self-promoting.

Comment: @K-H-W That was my original impulse as well, but the more I think about it the less sure I am.  The term "should" indicates a strong suggestion, but not an absolute requirement.  There are plenty of frivolous questions on this site - and yet the question "why do you want to know this" is one that the OP is not required to answer.  I.e, the reason / problem is the OP's own business.  As for promoting one's own sci-fi / fantasy works, the rules say "avoid self-promotion," but do not actually forbid it.  They only say to disclose affiliation, and not to self-promote on too many posts.

Comment: @MishaR -- I understand your point, but asking a question when you know the answer, but are not providing it.. that's basically a riddle or trivia contest; not really what this site is for.  As to the self-promotion, I find it distasteful, but harmless, if it's self-identified as such.. and that's the main thing that bothers me about this question; it wasn't identified as such, which disguised what it was.  Working hard to answer a question is fun, but discovering, after the fact, that it was just a way to show off something / advertise.. that just leaves a bad taste in the mouth.

Comment: @K-H-W, except it’s been done many times on the site.

Comment: @K-H-W That stock phrase from the help centre has [long](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1380/31394) been [agreed](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2865/31394) to be not a good fit for this particular SE site.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - That's fine, and perhaps it should be changed.. but even looking at the discussions you linked there is still the assumption of a real question -- As Beofett says  "I'm curious" is sufficient justification for asking a question" -- but when that's not even the case (like here) I worry that it's a slippery slope from valid curiosity questions to 'let me ask trivia questions about my work to spur interest in it' questions.  Perhaps I'm wrong, but, to me, that feels like a dangerous path to go down, that will lead away from actual questions and answers.

Comment: @K-H-W Sure, there might be a point at which we'd say "enough, this is spam". But until we reach that point, we don't need to close perfectly valid questions as long as all the rules on self-promotion are respected. (The same argument can be made for many types of question: "someone could ask a million questions like this and flood the site" doesn't mean the whole class of questions should be declared off-topic.)

Comment: @K-H-W I don't think that "I'm curious" is necessarily not the case here.  From the perspective of the artist, it may very well be "I'm curious whether the characters in my artwork are recognizable to other people."  It may or may not be the best use of the site, but it does mean the artist could be genuinely interested in the answer.

Comment: This is not an actual question, but a "game" in the form of a question. The author is the person who asked it, so it's not even that he/she doesn't know the answer.

Answer (score 25):

Some of this information is being obtained from the [official chat for this answer](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83753/discussion-on-answer-by-web-head-can-we-identify-all-the-characters-in-this-ult).

I created a 10x10 grid for this image to help keep track of what is being identified.

You can find it [by clicking this link](https://thesffblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/spacebattlegridded.png), since the image is too large to display properly here.

Bold indicates unsolved.
(In progress-note: Please edit only 1-2 items in at a time, to prevent overwriting others pending answers)

- A1

  - **Logo (raygun: maybe from Futurama?)**
- A2

  - **Debris**
- A3

  - **Screen with bat-like weapon or part**
- A4

  - Gundam (**RX-78-2 Gundam?**)
  - Spartan Shield, depicting the classic Λ for Lacedaemon
- A5

  - Ryuk from *Death Note*
  - **Portrait of Death or *Scream*-like character on a doorway**
- A6

  - Wave Motion Gun blast from *Space Battleship Yamato*
  - Petyr from *What We Do in the Shadows*
- A7

  - Tip of the Spear of Longinus from *Neon Genesis Evangelion*
- A8

  - Shaft of the Spear of Longinus (see A7)
  - **Broken white video screen or tablet**
- A9

  - Screen with icon for Invaders from Invader Zim
- A10

  - The Planet Express from *Futurama*
- B1

  - Empty
- B2

  - Megatron
- B3

  - King Kashekims Stone of *Disney's Atlantis: The Lost Empire*
- B4

  - Only contains overlap from other cells
- B5

  - Rathtar from *The Force Awakens*
  - Alien from *Alien* movie (being eaten)
  - Kerrigan, the Queen of Blades from *StarCraft II*
  - Senketsu from *Kill la Kill* (worn by Kerrigan)
  - Robot from original *Lost in Space* series
- B6

  - Holli Would from *Cool World*
  - Ken Washio from *Science Ninja Team Gatchaman* / Mark from *Battle of the Planets*
  - **Dance floor that says RPM**
  - **Zombie pilot**
  - Head of the Green Lion from *Voltron*
  - Squidward from *Spongebob Squarepants*
  - **Yellow slippers?**
  - Teleportation pod from *The Fly* (see also F10)
  - Cleveland Brown, Jr., from *The Cleveland Show* and *Family Guy* (kid eating popcorn, lower right)
  - BloodRayne
  - Chucky attacking a droog member from *A Clockwork Orange*
  - Captain Jack Sparrow is the other attacked person
  - Total Recall (1990) Memory trip device
- B7

  - Illuminati carpet
  - Pinky and Brain from *Pinky and the Brain*
  - Thing T. Thing, *The Addams Family*
  - **T-Rex skull from *Jurassic Park*?**
  - Kiki from *Kiki's Delivery Service*
  - ZET from *Zetman*
- B8

  - Atreyu riding Falkor from *The Neverending story*
- B9

  - Lightspeed briefs from Futurama
  - **buried robot in background**
- B10
- C1

  - Arzach (recognisable by his orange cape) riding his pterodactyl
  - **blue debris with a white letter E**
- C2

  - Front of the Swordfish from "Cowboy Bebop"
- C3

  - Dante from *Dante's Inferno* video game
  - Zodd from Bezerk
- C4

  - **number 15 on a spacecraft?**
  - 1010011010 (666 in binary code), number of the devil from *Futurama*
  - alien AKA the "thing" from *the Thing*
- C5

  - Wormhole from Sliders, *Sliders*
  - David Lo Pan, *Big Trouble in Little China*
  - Blade, Marvel
  - Zorg ZF-1 Pod Weapon, *Fifth Element* (held by Blade)
  - A Silent, *Doctor Who*
  - Johannes Krauser from *Detroit Metal City*
  - Vampire Band, *From Dusk Till Dawn*
  - Chaoseater sword from *Darksiders*
  - (Split between C5/D5) Dahaka from Prince of Persia: Warrior Within
  - Lagann from *Tengen Toppa Gurren Lagann*
- C6

  - The Warden, Superjail
  - [Tohru from _Jackie Chan's Adventures](https://jackiechanadventures.wikia.com/wiki/Tohru)
  - Master Chief from *Halo*
  - Eustace Bagge, Courage the Cowardly Dog (far right, gunner)
  - Number 5 / Johnny Five (on the dancefloor)
  - Jaws
  - Oblina *Aaahh Real Monsters*
  - Supply crates and infinite rocket crate from *Half-Life 2*
- C7

  - Bayonetta
  - Dante from *Devil May Cry*
  - Callie Maggotbone from Ugly Americans (being held)
  - Reaper from Overwatch
- C8

  - Callie Maggotbone from Ugly Americans (being held)
  - Tom from *Tom and Jerry*
  - Ronal the barbarian wielding Soulcalibur II Soul Edge
- C9

  - Omnidroid from *The Incredibles*
- C10
- D1

  - Vidscreen depicting *TRON* characters
- D2
- D3

  - Betelgeuse from *Beetlejuice*
  - Swordfish II from *Cowboy Bebop*
  - **purple goo with teeth?**
- D4

  - [Zoltar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQ0sHPD5JMg) from *Big*
  - Kiss-Shot Acerola-Orion Heart-Under-Blade from **Bakemonogatari**
- D5

  - Thomas the Tank Engine
  - Marvin the Martian, *Looney Tunes*
  - Robin Hood from *Robin Hood: Men In Tights*
- D6

  - Mike Wazowski, *Monsters, Inc.* (Gunner, left)
  - Kei Kishimoto from *Gantz*
  - Egg from *Ice Age3* (see also H7 and G9)
- D7

  - Forrest Gump with the Necronomicon in his lap.
  - Captain K'nuckles from *The Marvelous Misadventures of Flapjack*
  - Obelix from *Asterix the Gaul*
  - Cohen the Barbarian from Terry Pratchett's *Discworld*
  - *Robocop*
  - Momonga from *Overlord* (sitting on the desk)
  - Samara/Sadako from *The Ring*
  - Thumb-thumb from *Spy Kids*
- D8

  - CL4P-TP from *Borderlands*
  - Goddard the robot dog from *Jimmy Neutron*
  - Spaceman Spiff from *Calvin and Hobbes*
  - Robot dog from [*Chip 'n Dale Rescue Rangers*](https://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Robot_Dogs)
  - Cousin Itt from *The Addams Family*
  - Koromon from *Digimon*
  - Jerry from *Tom & Jerry*
  - The table including the elephant is from Zorg (Fifth Element) The whole room incl. table setting, chair and monitors is from scarface
  - Major Motoko Kusanagi from *Ghost in the Shell*
- D9

  - Abe from *Abe's Oddysey*
  - Aku Aku from *Crash Bandicoot*
  - Player and Spider from the game *Limbo*
- D10

  - Dragon constellation - from *Dragonheart*
- E1
- E2

  - ** Karen S'jet from Homeworld **
- E3

  - *Jumanji* board
  - Crypt Keeper from *Tales from the Crypt*
  - Monster book from *Harry Potter*
  - Gremlin from *Gremlins*
- E4

  - Rebecca "Revy" Lee from *Black Lagoon*
  - Shrek (in green glass)
  - Avatar Aang, in the form of a Minecraft character, holding the demon blood sword from Adventure Time.
  - Orange Portal
  - Metroid
  - 23 from *The Number 23* movie
  - Beheaded Kamikaze from the Serious Sam series
- E5

  - Scorpion from *Mortal Kombat* (bartender)
  - Gilius Thunderhead from Golden Axe
  - Inspector Gadget
  - Walter White from Breaking Bad (cooking)
  - One of the Street Sharks
  - 42
- E6

  - Donatello from *TMNT*
  - Cuphead
  - Figure from Attack on Titan
  - Raziel from *Legacy of Kain: Soul Reaver*
- E7

  - King Kong with cybernetics? Dissolving
- E8

  - One of the Battletoads
  - Marcus Fenix from *Gears of War*
  - Scooby-Doo
- E9

  - Portrait of Akku from *Samurai Jack*
  - Golden turd from *American Dad*
  - Waldo from *Where's Waldo?*
  - T-800 logo from *The Terminator*
  - Kirby ...**wearing a Marvel's Electro mask?** (notice how he throws lightning)
  - Matrix pod
- E10

  - Slayer from *The Suffering*
- F1

  - Glaive weapon from *Krull*
  - Alien creature from film *Riddick*
  - Stitch from Lilo & Stitch in Kratos paint with blades
- F2

  - Turnip Head from film  *Howl's Moving Castle*
  - Mojo Jojo, *Powerpuff Girls*
  - Dr Evil, *Austin Powers*...
  - ... holding Lord Nibbler from *Futurama*
  - Fantomas
  - kids from *Village of the Damned* (Mara Chaffee and David McGowan, probably)
  - Snidely Whiplash
  - Blueprint of the Nautilus from Disney's *20,000 Leagues Under the Sea*
  - Red Queen from the *Resident Evil* movies
  - Deacon from Waterworld
  - SHODAN from System Shock
  - SCP-682
- F3

  - Hannibal Lecter
  - (Top part of) Gelatinous Cube from D&D
  - Murderer in costume from Scream
  - Ark of the Covenant from *Indiana Jones*
  - Red Pikmin
  - Joker's body (hanging)
  - Anaconda, from the film of the same name
  - Inside of the Cube, from the movie *Cube*
  - Hologram of assorted *Star Wars* spaceships
- F4

  - Dory and Marlin from *Finding Nemo*
  - Robot from Nier Automata
  - Stimpy, from *The Ren & Stimpy Show*
  - Donkey Kong game (NES version) on screen
  - A Rune Shrine from Dishonoured
- F5

  - E.T. from the film of the same name
  - Worshiping Minion from *Despicable Me*
  - Wall-E (also worshiping)
  - Box from Metal Gear Solid (Solid Snake hides in it)
- F6

  - Nicholas D. Wolfwood from *Trigun*
  - Spyro the dragon
  - **Robot on line**
- F7

  - Hefer from *Rocko's Modern Life*
  - Alphonse Elric from *Fullmetal Alchemist*
  - Momo from *Avatar the Last Airbender*
- F8

  - Infinity Gauntlet from Marvel
  - Blue Portal
  - The Mask
  - Luffy from *One Piece*
  - Son Goku from *Dragon Ball*
  - Saitama from One Punch Man
  - Mug with question mark, notebook and pen of Stan from Gravity Falls
  - Reigen from *Mob Psycho 100*
- F9

  - Bugs Bunny
  - Mega Man
  - Zombie from *Half-Life 2*
  - Ash from Ash vs. the Evil Dead
  - Big Daddy from Bioshock
  - Beholder from D&D
  - Apollo command module
  - Whistlers Mother as fixed by Mr. Bean
  - Split between F9/F10, *The Master* from Fallout 1
  - Jorel's Brother from *Jorel's Brother*
- F10

  - Boogerman
  - Cartman from *South Park* in Gyro Gearloses Spaceship (seen in old DuckTales intro)
  - teleportation pod from *The Fly* (see also B6)
- G1
- G2

  - Borat (non-SFF character) on Magic Carpet from Disney's film *Aladdin*
  - Judge from *The Frighteners*
- G3

  - Pino in her pink bunny costume from *Ergo Proxy*
  - Fox Mulder's "I Want to Believe" poster
  - Dragon from *Dragon's Lair* videogame
  - Princess What's-her-name from *Earthworm Jim*
  - Lord Gwyn's crown from *Dark Souls*
  - Edward Scissorhands
  - Lucky Luke
  - Judge Dredd from 2000AD as "The Exorcist" priest
  - Mumm-ra from Thundercats? as "The Exorcist" possessed
  - **Sol 223.24** (Possible distance from Elite:Dangerous)
  - Frostmourne, Warcraft III
- G4

  - Kromm from *Aaah Real Monsters*
  - Iron Man suit (partial) hanging from crane
  - Donkey Kong Game on screen to the left
  - Lambda symbol from Half Life on small screen
  - Right Door Knocker from *Labyrinth*
  - **Half clothed female gunner**
  - **Head in a jar**
  - Casey Jones from *Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles*
- G5

  - Dr Manhattan from *Watchmen*
  - Nyancat
  - Split between G5/G6, Scorpius from Farscape
- G6

  - Captain Amelia from Disney's *Treasure Planet*
  - Star Gate Earth symbol on pillar
  - *The Kid* from Bastion shooting a gun
  - Kat from Gravity Rush
  - **screen with a black and white picture**
  - **weird pale kid in a tweed, shorts and no shoes**
  - **robot? whose telescopic arm reaches out to F5**
- G7

  - V's symbol from *V for Vendetta*
  - Sonic the Hedgehog
  - Tom Servo from *Mystery Science Theater: 3000*
  - Zora from *Zelda: Ocarina of Time*
  - M. Bison from *Street Fighter*
  - Kikuchiyo from *Samurai 7*
  - **Spider Jerusalem, Transmetropolitan?**
  - D from *Vampire Hunter D*
  - A Nurse from *Silent Hill*
  - Woola from the *John Carter* movie
- G8

  - Lrrr, ruler of the planet Omicron Persei 8, from *Futurama*
  - Jay and Silent Bob, from multiple Kevin Smith movies
  - Gir, from *Invader Zim*, riding a
  - Warrior Bug, from *Starship Troopers* (1997 movie version)
- G9

  - Patlabor Mecha from *Mobile Police Patlabor*
  - Egg from *Ice Age 3* (see also H7 and D6)
- G10

  - *Babylon 5* Starfury
  - *Star Wars* R2 Droid
  - Chilly Willy painted on the wing
  - Golden briefcase from *Pulp Fiction*
  - Scrooge McDuck
- H1
- H2

  - Kang/Kodos from *The Simpsons*
- H3

  - Half-section spacesuit, from *Planetes*, **holding what?**
- H4

  - **red spacecraft with a fin, a yellow stripe and a torpedo**
- H5

  - [RC Goblin](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/RC_Goblin), pink arrow from *GTA Vice City*
  - Devil from *Cow and Chicken*
  - Hollow Knight
  - **Giant yellow, square-shaped robot**
- H6

  - Shikaka from *Ace Ventura*
  - Pink *Splatoon* squid
  - Zev, holding Robot Head 790, both from Lexx
  - Worm from the game Worms
  - Agent 47 from *Hitman*
  - Dynamite from *GTA Vice City* mission: 'Demolition Man'
  - A Protectron from Fallout
  - Peter Pan's shadow
- H7

  - **The Stig from *Top Gear*?**...
  - ...riding Mario's kart from Mario Kart **(exact name?)**
  - Rick, from *Rick and Morty* (at bar, holding bottle over head)
  - **Simpson's character, Marge?**
  - Popeye the Sailor Man, from Popeye
  - Manny from Grim Fandango
  - Frank the Pug from *Men in Black*
  - Interdimensional portal from *Gravity Falls*
  - **Kneeling figure with candle/light hat?**
  - Laughing man symbol from Ghost in the Shell as head
  - "The Wall" tag from the eponymous Pink Floyd album cover (also one of the walking hammers)
  - Ted the Bellhop from Four Rooms
  - Egg from *Ice Age 3* (see also G9 and D6)
  - Phantom Spirit from *Final Fantasy: The Spirits Within*
- H8

  - Marvin the Paranoid Android, from 2005 Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy movie
  - Meg Griffin, from *Family Guy*
  - Voldemort from *Harry Potter* (both upper right corner)
  - The Dude from *The Big Lebowski*
  - The Invisible Man
  - Gabboid from *Tremors*
  - Vorlon Kosh from *Babylon 5*
  - Titeuf, also known as Tootuff
  - Room 237 from *The Shining*
  - Hole in wall from *Silent Hill 4*
  - Ohmu from Nausicaä of the Valley of the Wind
- H9

  - Tintin
- H10

  - **White eye from *Twilight Zone* intro?**
- I1

  - Destroyed Mad Cat (BattleTech)
- I2

  - Fire tracks from *Back to the Future*
- I3

  - Asteroids from the classic game
- I4

  - Spaceship and asteroids from the classic game Asteroids,  also on neighbouring tiles
  - Gargantua, the black hole from *Interstellar*
- I5

  - **skull with Native American headdress - from *Family Guy* episode "Petergeist"?**
  - Happy face spaceship from Heavy Metal
  - Conan the Barbarian
- I6

  - Dark Helmet from *Spaceballs*
  - Dracula
  - Alf holding a martini
  - Pennywise the clown from *It*
  - No Face from *Spirited Away*
  - Buffy (upside down on the Escher staircase)
  - Coraline
  - HAL from 2001
  - "Brooks was here" from *The Shawshank Redemption*
  - **White mouse-like creature with a sword under "Brooks was here"**
  - The Doom Slayer from Doom **in the Sarcophagus of the Mummy from the 90s *The Mummy* (there is the Hamunaptra Key)**
  - **Robot animal? (and what's behind it?)**
  - Daft Punk (piloting ship)
  - Martian from 1953 War of the Worlds
  - A Bonfire from Dark Souls
- I7

  - Adam Jensen from *Deus Ex*
  - Blue, red, yellow, pink and green Power Rangers' helmets on spikes
  - Xena, Warrior Princess
  - Lara Croft, from *Tomb Raider*
  - Klingon bat'leth sword
  - Popeye the Sailor Man
  - Head of elk from Happy Tree Friends on the wall
  - Johnny Mnemonic (in chair)
  - The Shadow (bottom left; red scarf and two guns)
  - The Golgothan from Dogma
  - Meliodas from *Seven Deadly Sins*
- I8

  - The Tet from *Oblivion*
  - **briefcase
  - **scythe?**
  - **guy with a trench coat holding two rifles, has a duffel bag**
  - Ripley from *alien*
- I9

  - Voyager probe (looks most similar to Voyager 1/2 based on the shape of the back of the main assembly and the number/size of antennae)
  - Coruscant from *Star Wars*
- I10

  - Elon Musk's Tesla
- J1

  - Fire trail from *Back to the Future*'s Delorean time machine
- J2

  - Sputnik 1
  - REDRUM door from *The Shining*
- J3
- J4

  - Astro Boy
  - Event Horizon (Ship)
- J5

  - Crab alien, the most known alien foe from *Space Invaders*
  - Tetsuo from Akira
- J6

  - Betty Boop
  - TIE Fighter from *Star Wars*
  - *Twilight Zone* clock
- J7

  - *E = mc²*, mass-energy equivalence
  - Silver Surfer being taken over by the Symbiote, both Marvel characters
  - Jigsaw from *Saw* in Invader Zim's spaceship
  - Paul
- J8

  - Pod (Clone Capsule) from the game EVE Online
  - The Tet (overlapping from I8)
- J9

  - Cromulon from Rick and Morty
  - Arrakis from *Dune*
- J10

  - **Just debris?**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83753/discussion-on-answer-by-web-head-can-we-identify-all-the-characters-in-this-ult).