# Looking for a canvas art of a space station full of famous Sci fi characters and ships

Tags: character-identification, art

Maybe a long shot...

A few weeks ago, I saw a post somewhere (I think it might have been here, not sure) asking for help identifying dozens of famous Sci-Fi characters and spaceships depicted in a canvas art of a space station. I can't find that post again, or the site that sells the canvas.

I remember small details, like Bill & Ted standing inside a Stargate in the upper-left corner. And Luke Skywalker in the lower-right foreground standing against a rail overlooking the scene. And a liquor bar in the middle with Quark working the counter.

Does this ring a bell for anyone?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/195553/can-we-identify-all-the-characters-in-this-ultimate-space-battle-poster ?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/ax3jzi/i_could_look_at_this_for_hours_so_many_characters/ ?

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi - the second one is the one, Bill & Ted appear in cell H1 - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205108/who-are-the-numerous-patrons-of-the-warp-core-cafe?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @fez yeah, just saw it)

Comment: Actually search is quite simple: "stargate identify bill ted"
Or even "stargate identify bill ted site:scifi.stackexchange.com"

Comment: Warp Core Cafe, that is the one! Thank you :-}

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are welcome =)